# NiFi processor scheduler runs only for one file

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version 1.5
i have a requirement and exploring the scheduler. just noticed that, the scheduler process only for one file irrespective of files presence. for example,

GenerateFlowFile -> UpdateAttribute -> LogAttribute

GenerateFlowFile runs every 10 seconds.
UpdateAttribute have scheduled 0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? * for every 1 minutes.

i noticed that, 6 files generated by GenerateFlowFile. And UpdateAttribute process only one file out of 6 files.

here, i want UpdateAttribute to run all the files in the queue for every 1 minute.

Comment: concurrency to 6

Comment: you mean to set concurrent tasks. But in real time, i wont be knowing how many files would be arriving to the scheduled processor.

Comment: then increase it more. I don't understand what do you want with those settings. It would depend on the purpose.

Comment: in real time, i would be getting many zip files. after unzipping the files, there will be 5 files in each zip. i should place in putFTP server location for every 1 hour. ideally, i would be queuing the unzipped files till putFTP processor. each hour, putFTP should run and place all the queued files in the server location.

Comment: how much concurrency tasks can we set in the processor? what is the impact in the NiFi.

Comment: In putftp there is a parameter `Batch Size` that I believe you need to set.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you only set a specific schedule on the source processor (GenerateFlowFile) in this case. All the processors after that should have run schedule of 0 seconds, which means run as fast as possible when data is in the preceding queue, otherwise don't run.